# Adding multiple syntax group to a syntax region

Tags: vimscript, syntax-highlighting, filetype

I’m writing a syntax file for [Bats](https://github.com/sstephenson/bats).  I started my syntax file by loading the bash syntax:

```
let g:is_bash=1
runtime! syntax/sh.vim
unlet b:current_syntax
```

I then defined the Bats custom keywords:

```
syntax match batsTestKeyword "\v\@test"
syntax keyword batsFunction load setup teardown run skip assert_success assert_failure assert_output
```

Finally, I’m trying to create a region that contains both the Bash syntax and the `batsFunction` keywords:

```
syntax region batsTestBlock start='{' end='}' contains=@bash, batsFunction
```

However when looking at a [test file](https://gist.github.com/aliou/3a27c3c736c7c0be7896498cc0459a79) only the Bash syntax is highlighted and not my custom syntax.

Any idea why my custom syntax is not included in the region?

Note: The keyword are linked as follows:

```
highlight default link batsTestKeyword  Identifier
highlight default link batsFunction Function
```

Comment: That's very odd. I copied your work, and it seems to work just fine for me. Here's a screenshot: http://i.andrewradev.com/ee29f978d71e940f6ceaa81c6dfd6191.png.

Is it possible that the filetype is not detected correctly? Have you checked that `:echo &ft` displays "bats"?

Comment: So this is not exactly what I'm expecting: I also want the bash syntax (`expected_version=$(cat $SNAP_ROOT/VERSION)`) to be highlighted as it is in a Bash file. `:echo &ft` correctly display `bats`.

Comment: Hi! Did you ever get anywhere with this? I'm getting sick of Syntastic barfing all over my BATS files. Leave a link to your project / code, if possible, for future visitors — thanks!

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE Yes! Check out the plugin repository [here](https://github.com/aliou/bats.vim).

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand from your comments, the problem is that the `@test { }` group to include bash syntax. One way I found to achieve this is by using `:syntax include` ([`:help :syn-include`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/syntax.txt.html#%3asyn%2dinclude)):

```
let g:is_bash=1

syntax include @BASH syntax/sh.vim
unlet b:current_syntax

runtime! syntax/sh.vim
unlet b:current_syntax

syntax match batsTestKeyword "\v\@test"
syntax keyword batsFunction load setup teardown run skip assert_success assert_failure assert_output

syntax region batsTestBlock start='{' end='}' contains=@BASH,batsFunction

highlight default link batsTestKeyword Identifier
highlight default link batsFunction Function
```

At the top, we include the bash syntax twice, once as the `@BASH` group, and once in the global namespace. The contained group can be added to the `contains=` list. You'd done that, actually, I assume from looking at some example, but you hadn't included the bash syntax group as that name.

I admit that syntax highlighting is not my strong suite, so there may be a better way of doing this, but this seems to work, in my experiments.

Comment: So for some reason that didn't work either, so I ended up saying that the bats keywords are contained in the `shExpr` syntax group from bash/sh. ([Example](https://github.com/aliou/bats.vim/blob/3e3459e74942d8ad00b967084248de15f1095765/after/syntax/bats.vim#L15-L23))